# 投票後、矢印の左右が統一していない

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 星を付けると、星もずれます: http://i.imgur.com/YFzVJ6g.png

Comment: @ento, 使っているブラウザとOSは何かを教えていただけますか？

Comment: Google Chrome 37.0.2062.94 / Mac OS X 10.9.5 です

Comment: @ento Retinaディスプレイですかね？

Comment: そうです! (そうかハードウェア情報も必要ですね)

Comment: @ento RetinaとRetinaじゃないの差で使っているスプライトが異なるらしいです。他のハードは関係ないと思います。

Comment: はい、ブラウザとOSだけじゃ環境を特定できないんだな (ディスプレイ=ハードウェアの情報も必要)、という意味で書きました

Comment: @ento　これは解決できたと思うが、確認よろしくお願いします。

Comment: メインでは解決していますが、メタではまだ再現します。[バッジの丸ぽちの件](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BF%E3%81%AE%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%B8%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7%E3%81%A7%E9%87%91%E9%8A%80%E9%8A%85%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%B8%E3%81%BD%E3%81%A1%E3%81%8C%E9%9A%A0%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B#comment138_231) と同じ原因の問題のようで、リンク先のコメントにあるようにCSSをいじったら解決しました